# Why is searching/evaluating an object column in a dataframe with 250milllion rows extremely slow?

Tags: python, pandas, performance

I have a dataframe of 235 million rows. One column in which is an object that has City names e.g) Chicago, Louxemburg etc.

When I do a simple pandas filter as:

```
result = data[(data['CITY'] == 'Louxemburg')]
```

It takes forever. More than 1.5 hrs.

And when i resort to DASK as follows:

```
ddask = dd.from_pandas(data, npartitions=15)
result = ddask[(ddask['CITY'] == 'Louxemburg')].compute(scheduler='processes')
```

It takes about 45 mins.

I really think a simple evaluation as such shouldnt be taking THIS long. Am I missing something ??

Comment: How many columns you dataframe have? 235e6 rows is a lot and so it should require a lot of memory. Actually, just the `CITY` field should take about 2 Go of memory. How much memory do you have? If you do not have enough, your OS will probably swap which is VERY slow (especially on HDD). Finally, what is the average size of the `CITY` strings?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how large your data is but based on what you shared, I believe you have an issue with your memory. There is a chance that no tool can help you if you need to load all the columns in each query. However, if you are planning to extract information from certain columns, Bodo is able to make your life much easier. Essentially, Bodo decreases memory usage by optimizing the sequential operations. For instance, Bodo frees up memory space by not loading the unused Parquet columns. You may find Bodo’s installation instructions at this link: https://docs.bodo.ai/latest/source/install.html

I slightly modified your code and used three columns instead of all columns. Then, I ran your code with Pandas which took around 6 minutes to run. Your data must have been much larger than mine as it is taking more than 1.5 hr to run. To increase the performance and scalability of the code, I ran the same code using Bodo, which took less than 25 seconds.

**Notes on data generation**: I generated a large dataset with 10 columns and 235 million rows. Then, I added another column called CITY, which is randomly filled with 24 city names. To make the generated data heavier, the rows of two other columns have been replaced with CITY column content, then the data saved as a Parquet file.

```
#data generation

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random

#making a 10 columns dataframe filled
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(235000000, 10), columns = list('ABCDEFGHIJ'))

#making the City column filled randomly from 24 city names

df['CITY'] = df['J'].apply(lambda x: random.choice(['Chicago', 'Tokyo', 'Delhi', 'Cairo', 
                                                       'Dhaka', 'Mumbai', 'Beijing', 'Osaka', 
                                                       'Mexico City', 'Shanghai', 'Sao Paulo', 
                                                       'Los angeles', 'Boston', 'San Diego', 'Louxemburg', 
                                                       'Austin', 'London', 'Denver', 'Pittsburgh',
                                                       'Orlando', 'Memphis', 'Phoenix', 'Tehran']))

#replacing two columns with CITY column
df['H'] = df['CITY']
df['I'] = df['CITY']

df.to_parquet("data.pq")
```

With Pandas:

```
import time 
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

start = time.time()
df = pd.read_parquet("data.pq")
df = df[['A','B','CITY']]
result = df.loc[df['CITY'] == 'Louxemburg']
end = time.time()
print("computation time: ", end - start)
print(result.head())

output:
computation time:  322.3528618812561
           A         B        CITY
1  -0.553538  1.214924  Louxemburg
16  1.191735  0.437258  Louxemburg
19 -0.973316 -0.220664  Louxemburg
27  0.481840  2.833082  Louxemburg
33  0.093671  0.142565  Louxemburg
```

With Bodo:

```
%%px
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import bodo
import time

@bodo.jit(distributed = ['df'])
def filter_data():
    start = time.time()
    df = pd.read_parquet("q3.pq")
    df = df[['A','B','CITY']]
    df = df.loc[df['CITY'] == 'Louxemburg']
    end = time.time()
    print("computation time: ", end - start)
    print(df.head())
    return df

df = filter_data()

output:
[stdout:0] 
computation time:  24.971635405003326
           A         B        CITY
1  -0.553538  1.214924  Louxemburg
16  1.191735  0.437258  Louxemburg
19 -0.973316 -0.220664  Louxemburg
27  0.481840  2.833082  Louxemburg
33  0.093671  0.142565  Louxemburg
```

Disclaimer: I work as a data scientist advocate in Bodo.ai.